# Angular DataTables: sName setting does not work

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm using the Angular-DataTables (jQuery Datatables) library, and while I can apparently set the sName value on the column:

```
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('sName', 'name')
```

It does not change the API request - it still uses the column index (in this case 0), which is meaningless to my API. However when I use the iDataSort option, it does work as expected:

```
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('iDataSort', 3)
```

...and the parameters passed to my API call function have 3 as the column identifier instead of 0.

Clarification: the issue is the actual parameters passed to the AJAX call always use the column index. I have this:

```
sitemapIndex.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withFnServerData(function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings){
       sitemapIndex.getSitemaps(aoData);
});
```

...where aoData contains the parameters used to construct the query string i use for the API. Regardless of sName setting (which is what I think is supposed to control this), the order item of the aoData array is always the index of the column (undesireable).

[image]

Am I missing an additional setting value somewhere to allow this option to be used?

Answer (score 1):

In your API request, did you append the `:name`?

For example, given this code:

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('name', 'foo'),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notVisible(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable()
];
```

you can fetch the data from the column named `foo` like this:

[image: Fetch data from column name]

More information on [DataTable's documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name).

Comment: I've added a clarification above. Adding a name option doesn't seem to have any effect. It also looks like this solution could be for a more customized task, I'm trying to get it working with the default sorting function on the front end (adjusting my backend to fit).